# What that means by "I am willing to try the code as is"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

My colleague and I have been working on a software project. I recently proposed some changes to the code base and requested for his review. He then added some comments as below:

> Now that I see you have created the "keys" list, I can see that the list having items erased from it is not the one being iterated on. I am willing to try the code as is.

The first sentence simply means he now understands the changes that I have made. But I am not sure what the later sentence means. Does it mean he agrees with the changes or does he want to keep the original code?

Comment: 'As is', sometimes written 'as-is', means 'as it is, without changes'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It means he prefers the original one (without changes)?

Comment: He is willing to try it. That's all.

Comment: I suggest you ask your collegue.  It's not obvious if it means "without the changes" or "without further changes".